# How to test which element has focus with React and testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing-library

I am working on a react app using mainly functional components. This is all tested with the react - testing library. I would like to test the focus of some elements to show that after some interactions certain elements gain focus but I cant see anything to support this.
Is it possible ?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, it's possible by using `jest-dom`'s [toHaveFocus matcher](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavefocus).

Answer (score 1):

A good trick to know is matching to a CSS selector, like so:

```
expect(foo.matches(':focus')).toBe(true)
```

You can do much more with it, but be careful not to make the test too brittle, by checking the implementation details of the tree (for example, don't do anything like `foo.matches('.thing > div + span ~ div')`).

Answer (score -2):

use document.activeElement is the answer